# google load balancing path matching pattern priority

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I want to have request for `HOST/code4/*` to go to `backb` and rest all to `backa` .

i only defined one rule while setting up the host and path as `HOST=* , PATH=/code4, /code4/* , BACKEND=backb`

But when i look in to console it shows hosts as shown in image with a extra rule of `/*` due to which my request i think my request to `/code4` goes to `backa`.

**What am i doing wrong ?**

**Why google is adding a `/*` route?** Even if its adding then unmatch route make no sense, right ?

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, is it possible that the rule was accidentally added by yourself?

Comment: @Dagang Today /code4 goes to backb , so probably it might be taking to much time yesterday to update , but it still add /* by itself